# Overlay images on top of another without any fading

Tags: image-processing, graphicsmagick

I have a series of images. What I wish to do is to literally superimpose these images on top of each other without any other manipulation. The actual example is below

**This is the first image**

[image: This is the first image]

**This is the second image**

[image]

There are five samples like this, each with a tooltip on top of the bar. Essentially, the final image needs have the bars in their full green color with the tool tips showing up on each bar.

The closest I've been able to come up with was using GraphicsMagick which unfortunately does the following with its "average" command.

[image]

Any other pointers on how to accomplish this?

Finally: While at this time I just want to get the job done, long term, I will ideally want to use some commandline tool like GraphicsMagick without the need to have a desktop software installed.

Comment: so creating your own graph is not an option? why would you superimpose overlapping "tooltips"? how often do you need this? this is not a development service btw. you should propose some own ideas if you want any help

Comment: You can do this with a minimum of PhotoShop skill. There is no programming involved.

Comment: @Piglet, I have mentioned what I tried and have posted my result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `darken` blend mode in ImageMagick:

```
convert 1.png 2.png 3.png -compose darken -composite result.png
```

[image]

You'd have to tidy up your cropping first though!

Comment: thank you. your approach worked. However, the latest gm version spun off composite to its own command so I had to do this:

`gm composite /tmp/12.png /tmp/8.png -compose darken /tmp/12.png`

As well, the latest [manual for gm](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-compose) did not reference the darken modifier though it works.